# How can I tell if I don't get e-mail

Tags: email, monitoring

That sounds a little silly but bear with me...

I have several servers which run several automated processes which each e-mail me status reports (e.g., build success or failure).  However, there are enough systems and enough processes that it is hard to intuitively assess if one of the servers goes off line or one of the processes completely fails in a way that doesn't send e-mail.  I want something like a Thurderbird plugin that I can configure with "I expect to receive 3 messages from server1 and 4 from server2 every night between midnight and 4am" (or something) and have it tell me: "Didn't hear from server1 last night."  I can write filters that act on things happening, but I want to be notified when something fails to happen.  Any thoughts?

Comment: you may consider using something like nagios , https://www.nagios.org/ to monitor your server rather than using emails.

Comment: It's better to use naggios with nagstamon or zabbix to monitor problems on your servers. Right now monitoring with emails isn't best practice and pretty hard.

Comment: Another one way is to have tags in subject something like [SERVER1] or [SERVER2] and make separate folder for each tag.